# Android - fire a function after activity animation ends

Tags: android, events, animation, transition

I have the following code:

```
    showButtonSpinner(view);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, activity);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.hold);
    hideButtonSpinner(view);
```

Is it possible to run `hideButtonSpinner(view);` after the transition ends?

Right now i have to set a timer and run the function after a 1000ms delay, but the thig is that the animation can take longer due to a lag or something else and the spinner disappears too early.

EDIT: I should mention, that i am looking for a way to do it all in the parent activity to avoid extra code in all the child activities.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: you can send a "handler" message to Activity A(which contains spinner)  from Activity B

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yeah, thats one way to do it, but i am looking for a way to do it in the parent activity (i've edited the question).